# Log in with Facebook still returns user although login was cancelled

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-login

I'm using the Parse SDK to support login with Facebook. However if I cancel the login view ("Not now" button on the bottom left), then the following method still returns a user.

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
 }];
```

Normally it should jump into the first if-statement, but weirdly the `PFUser` object is not nil and it jumps into the second if-statement. That means it successfully created a user in the backend, although the login was cancelled.

I'm requesting the following permissions:

```
NSArray *permissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
```

Comment: What fields are set on the new PFUser? I might be seeing a similar issue.

Comment: I think it's only username.

Comment: Is the username a long alphanumeric string?

Comment: Yes, it is. I think this is just a hashed string of the username, I also can see the correct Facebook ID in the Parse Core Backend (Data).

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing this too. What Parse library version are you on? It could be a bug on their end

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm using SDK version 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that I've seen for over a year and had to deal with locally. The way that I ultimately solved it was by deleting that new PFUser from the server if the user cancelled their signup process. It's also setup so that if they don't cancel(leave the app) and then return they can continue/complete the signup process. I don't know how your app is setup or the use application, but for me it was a no brainer to add in a cancel signup process action. From there deleting the current progress made to creating a new user just makes sense.